# Get 2 doubles from a string

Tags: java, string

I am passing some data from another class. This string I pass is:

> "23 n 5"

Now I have 2 instance Double variables called a and b.

My aim is to take this and place 23 in a and 5 in b. The n is a splitter. Any number can be either side.

i'm sure the code must be really simple here. But, i'm not sure what to put in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  public Double x(String x){
        if (x.contains(" n ")){
 <code need help on> }
```

Comment: "The n is a splitter" you are on right track.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String[] split = input.split(" n ");  // the argument can be a regular expression
```

Comment: I added a link to the official docs, which note that the param is technically always a regex (may vary by JDK version).

Answer (score 4):

```
public void x(String x)
{
    if (x.contains(" n "))
    {
        String[] s = x.split(" n ");
        a = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
        b = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
String[]arr=x.trim().split("n");
double a=Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
double b=Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Given the input, it might be more useful to split prior to trimming.